# unix shell scripting to find and remove unwanted string in a pipe delimited file in a particular column

Tags: unix, awk, sed, split, grep

{
I have a requirement, where the file is pipe "|" delimited.
The first row contains the headers, and the count of columns is 5.

I have to delete only the string in the 3rd column if it matches the pattern.

Also note the 3rd column can contain strings with commas `,`, semicolon `;` or colon `:` but it will never contain a pipe `|` (due to which we have chosen a pipe delimiter).

Input File:

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5
1|CRIC|IPL|CRIC1:IPL_M1;IPL_M2;TEST_M1,CRIC2:ODI_M1;IPL_M3|C1|D1
2|CRIC|TEST|CRIC1:TEST_M2,CRIC2:ODI_M1;IPL_M1;TEST_M2;IPL_M3;T20_M1|C2|D2
```

Output should change only in COL3 no other columns should be changed, i.e. in COL3 the string which matches the pattern 'IPL_' should be present.
Any other strings like "TEST_M1","ODI_M1" should be made null.
And any unwanted semi colons should be removed.

eg

```
Question - CRIC1:IPL_M1;IPL_M2;TEST_M1,CRIC2:ODI_M1;IPL_M3
result   - CRIC1:IPL_M1;IPL_M2,CRIC2:IPL_M3
```

Another scenario where if only strings that do not match "IPL_" are present then

```
Question -  CRIC1:TEST_M1,CRIC2:ODI_M1
Result   -  CRIC1:,CRIC2:
```

Output File:

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5
1|CRIC|IPL|CRIC1:IPL_M1;IPL_M2,CRIC2:IPL_M3|C1|D1
2|CRIC|TEST|CRIC1:,CRIC2:IPL_M1;IPL_M3|C2|D2
```

Basic requirement is to find and replace the string,

INPUT

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5
1|A1|A12|A13|A14|A15
```

Replace A13 with B13 in column 3 (A13 can change, I mean we have to find any pattern like A13)

OUTPUT

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5
1|A1|A12|B13|A14|A15
```

Thanks in advance.

Re formatting the scenario in simpler terms,by taking only 2 columns, where I need to search "IPL_" and keep only those strings and any other string like "ODI_M3;TEST_M5" should be deleted

{

I/P:

{

COL1|COL2

CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2;TEST_M1

CRIC2|ODI_M1;IPL_M3

CRIC3|ODI_M3;TEST_M5

CRIC4|IPL_M5;ODI_M5;IPL_M6

}

O/P:

{

COL1|COL2

CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2

CRIC2|IPL_M3

CRIC3|

CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M6

}

Awaiting your precious suggestions.
Please help I'm new to this platform.

Thanks,
Saquib
}

Comment: Not clear, please WRAP your code in CODE TAGS by using button `{}` and mention the conditions clearly too in your post.

Comment: INPUT
 


COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

1|A1|A12|A13|A14|A15

Replace A13 with B13

OUTPUT

COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

1|A1|A12|B13|A14|A15

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, I have added a simple scenario.
Could you please help now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, they are still NOT in code tags. Simple select all your sample then click on `{}` button in BAR and they will come in code tags, it will make our life easier to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly (and I'm not entirely sure I am; I'm going mostly by the provided examples), then this could be done relatively sanely with Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) {
    if($. > 1) {
        local @F = split /\|/;

        $F[3] = join(",", map {
            local @H = split /:/;
            $H[1] = join(";", grep(/IPL_/, split(";", $H[1])));
            join ":", @H;
        } split(/,/, $F[3]));

        $_ = join "|", @F;
    }

    print;
}
```

Put this code into a file, say `foo.pl`, then if your data is in a file `data.txt` you can run

```
perl -f foo.pl data.txt
```

This works as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Read lines from input (in our case: data.txt)
while(<>) {
    # In all except the first line (the header line):
    if($. > 1) {
        # Apply the transformation. To do this, first split the line into fields
        local @F = split /\|/;

        # Then edit the third field. This has to be read right-to-left at the top
        # level, which is to say: first the field is split along commas, then the
        # tokens are mapped according to the code in the inner block, then they
        # are joined with commas between them again.
        $F[3] = join(",", map {
            # the map block does a similar thing. The inner tokens (e.g.,
            # "CRIC1:IPL_M1;IPL_M2") are split at the colon into the CRIC# part
            # (which is to be unchanged) and the value list we want to edit.
            local @H = split /:/;

            # This value list is again split along semicolons, filtered so that
            # only those elements that match /IPL_/ remain, and then joined with
            # semicolons again.
            $H[1] = join(";", grep(/IPL_/, split(";", $H[1])));

            # The map result is the CRIC# part joined to the edited list with a colon.
            join ":", @H;
        } split(/,/, $F[3]));

        # When all is done, rejoin the outermost fields with pipe characters
        $_ = join "|", @F;
    }

    # and print the result.
    print;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But we have a requirement to use AWK or SED